# Task OutOfMemory exception does not terminate process

Tags: c#, exception, task-parallel-library

I have the following code of a task with a successful and on faulted continuations.

```
Task<IEnumerable<IDictionaryObject>> getParameters = _parametersRequester.BeginGetParametersBulk(requestJob);

var processParameters = 
getParameters.ContinueWith((x) =>
    {
         //Do some processing
    }, TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnRanToCompletion);

getParameters.ContinueWith((x) =>
    { 
        AggregateException ex = x.Exception;
        ex.Flatten().Handle(ie => HandleException(requestJob, canRetry, ie));
    }, TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnFaulted);

return processParameters;
```

HandleException retries some operations if occurred exception is known and returns false if it hits unknown exception.
The problem I see is that *getParameters* throws OutOfMemoryException which should terminate the process when GC finalizers run but they don't seem to run thus process is still running and in unstable state.

Is there any way to force the process to terminate if HandleException returns false?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Exceptions not handled by `Handle` are repackaged into a new `AggregateException` and rethrown.

In .NET 4.5, the default behaviour is that unobserved Task exceptions do not take down the process.

To change this (and restore .NET 4.0 behaviour), add the following to your app configuration:

```xml
<configuration> 
    <runtime> 
        <ThrowUnobservedTaskExceptions enabled="true"/> 
    </runtime> 
</configuration>
```

See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.taskscheduler.unobservedtaskexception%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for more info.

You are probably better off observing the exception and if no graceful shutdown is possible, at least report the exception with your application logging or something like:

```
System.Environment.Failfast("Meaningful error message.", exception);
```

Comment: Thanks for answer James. This is 4.0 though which is weird why it wouldn't take down the process. I read something about GC to having run finalizer on that task before that happens which is also not happening in my case.

Comment: Do you have .NET 4.5 *installed*? If so, that's all you need for this to apply... (It's an in place upgrade that affects apps compiled for .NET 4.0 too... I know! Sucks right?)

Comment: Nope no 4.5 installed on that box.